# How to rapidly create array of N 3x3 matrices from 9 arrays of size N?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

Assume that I have 9 arrays (A, B, C, .. J) of size N. I want to create a new array of N 3x3 matrices such that e.g.

```
matrices[i] = [[A[i], B[i], C[i]],
               [D[i], E[i], F[i]],
               [G[i], H[i], J[i]]]
```

A simple solution is to add each entry to the array `matrices` in a for-loop as:

```
for i in range(len(matrices)):
    matrices[i] = [[A[i], B[i], C[i]],
            [D[i], E[i], F[i]],
            [G[i], H[i], J[i]]]
```

Anybody got some tips on how this can be done in a faster, vectorized way avoiding the for-loop? If there exists some smart indexing operations or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to stack those in columns with [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) and reshape with [`np.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) -

```
np.column_stack((A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J)).reshape(-1,3,3)
```

Concatenating with [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) is known to be much faster, so using it with `2D transpose` and reshaping -

```
np.concatenate((A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J)).reshape(9,-1).T.reshape(-1,3,3)
```

Another with `np.concatenate`, `3D transpose` and reshaping -

```
np.concatenate((A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J)).reshape(3,3,-1).transpose(2,0,1)
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [59]: # Setup input arrays
    ...: N = 1000
    ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: C = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: D = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: E = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: F = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: G = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: H = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: J = np.random.randint(0,9,(N,))
    ...: 

In [60]: %timeit np.column_stack((A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J)).reshape(-1,3,3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 84.4 µs per loop

In [61]: %timeit np.concatenate((A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J)).reshape(9,-1).T.reshape(-1,3,3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.8 µs per loop

In [62]: %timeit np.concatenate((A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J)).reshape(3,3,-1).transpose(2,0,1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: That's a great solution, the speed up is enormous! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Tried to time it to, if all arrays contain 50 million elements the first solution takes approx 7 seconds, the second solution 3 seconds.

Great! Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @Selvin Yup, getting similar results, that I just added.