# Insert elements to beginning and end of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 56, 4, 8, 564])
```

and I want to add two elements: one at the beginning of the array, `88`, and one at the end, `77`.

I can do this with:

```
a = np.insert(np.append(a, [77]), 0, 88)
```

so that `a` ends up looking like:

```
array([ 88,   2,  56,   4,   8, 564,  77])
```

The question: what is the correct way of doing this? I feel like nesting a `np.append` in a `np.insert` is quite likely not the pythonic way to do this.

Comment: So we've had `hstack` and `concatenate` as answers. In practice, is there a performance difference between the two (e.g. if inserting large arrays?)

Comment: @areuexperienced I just ran some timing and concatenate was consistently ~3x faster than hstack regardless of array length. Has anyone else found similar results?

Comment: @J.Corson Yes, that is expected and follows the same pattern as discussed in [`this solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32697426/3293881)

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! I hadn't seen that post.

Comment: `insert`, `append`, even `hstack` all use `np.concatenate`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Another way to do that would be to use [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) . Example -

```
np.concatenate([[88],a,[77]])
```

Demo -

```
In [62]: a = np.array([2, 56, 4, 8, 564])

In [64]: np.concatenate([[88],a,[77]])
Out[64]: array([ 88,   2,  56,   4,   8, 564,  77])
```

Comment: Since apparently all other options make use of `np.concatenate`, I'll select this answer that goes right to the source. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the list of indices to [`np.insert`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) :

```
>>> np.insert(a,[0,5],[88,77])
array([ 88,   2,  56,   4,   8, 564,  77])
```

Or if you don't know the length of your array you can use `array.size` to specify the end of array :

```
>>> np.insert(a,[0,a.size],[88,77])
array([ 88,   2,  56,   4,   8, 564,  77])
```

Comment: @J.Corson No `-1` won't work in this case it will insert the `77` before 564

Comment: `>>> np.insert(a,[0,-1],[88,77])
array([ 88,   2,  56,   4,   8,  77, 564])`

Comment: Good call. Totally forgot about that.

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't do any benchmarking. Performance-wise, this might be the worst if `np.array` works like normal python lists as we have to do shifting `x` times where x is the number of items we'll add to array.

Comment: @ozgur Yes, if we are dealing with longer lists It wouldn't be an efficient way for this task, but it is more flexible for several tasks and performs good with small arrays!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
np.concatenate(([88],a,[77]))
```

Answer (score 5):

what about:

```
a = np.hstack([88, a, 77])
```