# Add list to end of a list of array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, insert

I want to add a list of elements at the end of the arrays of a list. I tried to use `np.insert`function like this :

```
dataForModel=np.insert(dataForModel, -1, output_recoded, axis=1)
```

where  `dataForModel` is a list of arrays and `sampling_times`is a 1-D list whose length is the same as `len(dataForModel)`. So what I want is to put one (corresponding) element of `output_recoded`at the end of each array contained in `dataForModel`

The problem is, it puts `output_recoded` *before* the last column of the basic `dataForModel`but I want it to be after.

For example if my data were `dataForModel=[array([2,15,-3,4]), array([12,1,3,42]),array([6,8,21,-5])]` and `output_recoded` is [101,47,82], I would like to have `[array([2,15,-3,4,101]), array([12,1,3,42,47]),array([6,8,21,-5,82])]`

Thanks for help

Comment: Use `np.append` rather than `np.insert`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32828922/6770307) post gives a few options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataForModel=np.insert(dataForModel, dataForModel.size, sampling_times, axis=1)
```

Example:

```html
>>> a = np.array([2, 56, 4, 8, 564])
>>> np.insert(a, -1, [1,2,3])
array([  2,  56,   4,   8,   1,   2,   3, 564])
>>> np.insert(a, a.size, [1,2,3])
array([  2,  56,   4,   8, 564,   1,   2,   3])
```

Update:

```html
>>> dataForModel=[np.array([2,15,-3,4]), np.array([12,1,3,42]),np.array([6,8,21,-5])]
>>> dataForModel=np.array(dataForModel)
>>> dataForModel
array([[ 2, 15, -3,  4],
       [12,  1,  3, 42],
       [ 6,  8, 21, -5]])
>>> output_recoded= [101,47,82]
>>> dataForModel=np.insert(dataForModel, dataForModel.shape[1], output_recoded, axis=1)
>>> dataForModel
array([[  2,  15,  -3,   4, 101],
       [ 12,   1,   3,  42,  47],
       [  6,   8,  21,  -5,  82]])
```

If you are trying to add an ending column, keep in mind the data added needs to match the dimensions of `(dataForModel.shape[1],1)` dimension

Comment: Why do I still get this error :`IndexError: index 11363840 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 23` when I write this line of code : `dataForModel=np.insert(dataForModel, dataForModel.size, output_recoded, axis=1)` ? However, len(output_recorded)=len(dataForModel)=494080 Please @StevenRumbalski, @Grant McCloskey

Comment: For info, 11363840=494080*23 and the size of the arrays is 23 before trying to do the insert

Comment: Get the same issue when using `len(dataForModel)` with index 494080 causing trouble

Comment: Axis 0 is the first dimension (the "rows"), and axis 1 is the second dimension (the "columns"). I imagine you just need to remove the axis keyword arg. Unless the behavior of insert you need is different
`dataForModel=np.insert(dataForModel, dataForModel.shape[1], sampling_times, axis=1)`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Nope, that does not work, I think I need `axis=1`otherwise it gives a disaster. I edited my post to make you understand what I am looking for and hope it will allow to explain the error above that I still get without understanding

Comment: Will update again- Please check update on my answer and let me know if that helps

Comment: That does ! Thank you Grant !

Answer (score 0):

My first bet would be a `for` loop, though there are probably more efficient ways to do this:

```
for i in range(len(dataForModel)):

    dataForModel[i] = [*dataForModel[i], sampling_times[i]]
```

The `*` will unpack the current array into a new list, though you could `append` as well