# sort multible numpy arrays into one like: [1,2,..n, 1,2..n]

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting, numpy, beagleboneblack

I have six numpy arrays which i need to convert into one array or even better, a list (if there is a faster way as tolist() you would like to recommend me). Anyways, i need this for processing the image data from a .gif, so it has to be very fast. My recent try ended in a 8Frames/s processing time. I converted the arrays into lists, but i am pretty sure if it could be done with array-methods it would be faster.

The arrays have the same lenght, they are one-dimensional, have a lenght from 4096 and are filled with boolean-values.

principial it should do follow:

```
a = array((1,3,5))
b = array((2,4,6))

>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

So here's my recent try:

```
for x in range(size):
    counter += 1
    print(b0[x]
    data_bin.insert(0, 0)
    data_bin.insert(1, 0)
    data_bin.insert(2, b0[x])
    data_bin.insert(3, b1[x])
    data_bin.insert(4, r0[x])
    data_bin.insert(5, g0[x])
    data_bin.insert(6, r1[x])
    data_bin.insert(7, g1[x])
```

then i write data_bin to a memory space and clear the value. I can write 1 Frames in 10ms, so the whole routine should cost me about 8ms.

To suppress confusions, i get the data from the images in an array format and have to get them in the right order. Afterwards i must convert it to a string due it's the fastest way for me to write it to the memory.

Thanks :)

Comment: So, basically you want to `zip` and `chain` the arrays? Sort of like `[x for y in zip([1,3,5],[2,4,6]) for x in y]`, just faster and using numpy?

Comment: I am still not sure how your first example related to the second. Are you sure the intended ordering is correct? How would `r0, r1, g0, g1, b0, b1` relate to `a` and `b`?

Comment: @tobias_k ohh sorry, the first example is only a demonstration which it should do, the second is from my code, i didn't change something. So the orde should be like `code[0, 0, b0[x], b1[x], r0[x], g0[x], r1[x], g1[x]]`(The first two bits are offset). And then repeat it till x = 4096

Comment: Then, have you tried something like (in plain Python) `[(0, 0) + zipped for zipped in zip(b0, b1, r0, g0, r1, g1)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are *inserting* elements from the six inputs one-by-one, but starting from the last element until the first one for each input. Basically this is a concatenation process, with zeros being appended at regular intervals (`2+6`).

One approach to do this efficiently instead of the looping, would be with [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
size = len(b0)  # Must be 4096

# Initialize output as a 2D array with zeros that would also hold all elements 
# from the six inputs
out = np.zeros((size,8),dtype=b0.dtype)

# Leave first two elements in each row and 
# put inputs-concatenated and flipped version into the output array  
out[:,2:] = np.concatenate((b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1)).reshape(-1,size)[:,::-1].T 

# Finally convert to list if needed
data_bin_out = out.ravel().tolist()
```

Runtime tests and verify output -

1) Setup inputs:

```
In [2]: # Inputs
   ...: size = 4096
   ...: b0 = np.random.randint(2,9,(size))
   ...: b1 = np.random.randint(2,9,(size))
   ...: r0 = np.random.randint(2,9,(size))
   ...: g0 = np.random.randint(2,9,(size))
   ...: r1 = np.random.randint(2,9,(size))
   ...: g1 = np.random.randint(2,9,(size))
   ...:
```

2) Define methods -

```
def concat_app(b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1):
    out = np.zeros((size,8),dtype=b0.dtype)
    out[:,2:] = np.concatenate((b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1)).reshape(-1,size)[:,::-1].T 
    return out.ravel().tolist()

def org_app(b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1):
    data_bin = []
    counter = 0
    for x in range(size):
        counter += 1
        data_bin.insert(0, 0)
        data_bin.insert(1, 0)
        data_bin.insert(2, b0[x])
        data_bin.insert(3, b1[x])
        data_bin.insert(4, r0[x])
        data_bin.insert(5, g0[x])
        data_bin.insert(6, r1[x])
        data_bin.insert(7, g1[x])
    return data_bin
```

3) Timings and verification:

```
In [4]: %timeit org_app(b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1)
1 loops, best of 3: 556 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit concat_app(b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 648 µs per loop

In [6]: concat_app(b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1) == org_app(b0,b1,r0,g0,r1,g1)
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: i have to apologize me ! your solution is way faster than @RutkerKassies solution. Both are working for my purpose but instead of ~50ms (@Rutker) it takes about 566µs, as your verification also confrimed. Thank you !! :)

Comment: @InvAdErZz Not surprised at all. `np.concatenate` is internally used in other stacking funcs like `np.hstack`, `np.vstack`, etc., so you are avoiding the func calls overhead with it. See here for some related benchmarks - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32697426/3293881

Answer (score 2):

Based on your desired output i would say:

```
np.dstack((a, b)).flatten()

array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

But the context is a bit unclear. What type of arrays do you start with? In any case, i would stick to Numpy as much as possible, and avoid a lot of list manipulations. Inserting into a list element by element would probably cause many reallocation's of the list, because the size continues to expand. That's unnecessary since you already now the size beforehand.